# On submit, my Edit Form flashes initial values then shows updated values?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-final-form

In my project, I have a React Final Form form for editing an entity. It is first populated with the initial values. You can update the values, then click submit. On submit, it calls a GraphQL mutation using Apollo Client, which has a refetch query to refetch the entity.

For some reason, when I click submit, the form shows the initial values for a second (I checked, and the form is re-rendering with `initialValues` set to the initial values) Then after the mutation's refetch query happens, the form shows the updated values (it re-renders with `initialValues` set to the updated values). Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent it?

This is what the behavior looks like:
[Screen Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMco.gif)

The code looks something like this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-almeida-j3mdul?file=/src/App.js. I can't replicate the behavior there unfortunately (partly because I'm using a fake API), but as you can see in this screen recording it's happening in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to define and update the values of the form fields. This will avoid this kind of artifact.